# Grant role to "class" in spring security

Tags: grails, spring-security

Here's a (fictive) structure  (sorry, I know I don't have a strong imagination) which to resembles the structure of my application:
(Person, SuperPerson and NormalPerson are abstract):

[image: Persons Hierarchy]

I'm wondering if I can grant roles to each class (so all the instances of this class will get these rights) using spring security in Grails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Spring Security grants roles at the instance, not class, level.

There are two ways to grant authorities (permissions):

1. Grant them directly to a principle (user)
2. Grant them to a group (role), and then add principles to the groups containing the authorities then need.

So in your case, you can take the role-based approach and have each class represented by a role. Then, when you create an instance of a class, add it to the appropriate role.

### Example of using a service to grant authorities

```
class PersonService {

    private Map authorityGroups = [
        Person: ['Person'],
        NormalPerson: ['Person', 'NormalPerson'],
        Employee: ['Person', 'NormalPerson', 'Employee'],
        ...
    ]

    Person create(Class klass, Map props) {
        def person = klass.newInstance(props)
        def groups = getGroupsForClass(klass)

        person.save()

        groups.each {
            new PersonAuthorityGroup(authorityGroup: it, person: person).save()
        }
    }

    private Collection<AuthorityGroup> getGroupsForClass(Class klass) {
        authoritiyGroups[klass.simpleName].collect {
            AuthorityGroup.findByName(it)
        }
    }
}
```

The service can then be used like this:

```
def a = personService.create(Person, [first: 'John', last: 'Galt'])
def b = personService.create(SuperPerson, [first: 'Jane', last: 'Smith'])
```

Comment: should this be done in the constructor? (granting authorities/binding roles)

Comment: No, you'd be better off doing it in a controller, service, or using `beforeCreate()` on the domain class. To me, the approach friendliest to unit testing is using a service. Also, remember that a domain class constructor gets called every time an instance is created in the JVM, such as when you retrieve an instance with GORM.

Comment: thank you for the example, but won't be redundant to have spring security role + table per hierarchy discriminant column  ?  and I didn't understand this part :
authoritiyGroups[klass.simpleName].collect {
            AuthorityGroup.findByName(it)
        }